# sql/dplyr regexp_extract : alternative to pos-lookaround which spits out error

Tags: sql, r, regex, dplyr

I'm trying to query something using dplyr in R and since dplyr doesnt have a direct function translation for str_extract (or other substring extracting operators), I opted to write that piece of the code in sql. Problem is the regex patterns that R accepts seem to differ from sql (or more precisely the regexp_extract function). My regex to look-around the ":" character gets errors saying it is invalid. Is there an alternative regex pattern to use or any other workaround?

Goal of the regex is to capture the numbers AFTER the colon-> Ex. "VBEEUJTHRJV:12345"

Code:

> REGEXP_EXTRACT(column,'(?<=:)([0-9]*)',0)

Error Message:

> Could not compile regexp pattern: (?<=:)([0-9]*)
> Error: invalid perl operator: (?<
> )

Comment: Where is `REGEX_EXTRACT` defined? I'm having a hard time finding it.

Comment: it appears to be a SQL function @r2evans https://docs.data.world/documentation/sql/reference/functions/regexp_extract.html

Comment: @A03 it might be good to include your code in here. It's unclear right now if you're having a problem with the R part of your code, or the SQL part

Comment: @Mark The message looks similar enough to R errors that I wasn't sure, thanks for finding the Oracle reference. A03, it seems like this is really just a SQL question, since the problem is not on the R side, is that correct? Can you confirm you're connecting to Oracle?

Comment: @r2evans I'm actually connecting to impala but yes this is more of an sql question than an R one (it's spitting out the sql error through the function "SQL" in dplyr). I did solve my problem however by employing the regex ':([0-9]+)'. Seemed to work fine for what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did solve my problem however by employing the regex `':([0-9]+)'`. Seemed to work fine for what I needed

- [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76789474/sql-dplyr-regexp-extract-alternative-to-pos-lookaround-which-spits-out-error#comment135400516_76789474)